# How to prove $x^{2n}-1=(x^2-1)\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(x^2-2x\cos\frac{k\pi}{n}+1\right)$ if $n$ is a positive integer.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

> Prove that $$x^{2n}-1=(x^2-1)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(x^2-2x\cos\frac{k\pi}{n}+1\right)$$
> if $n$ is a positive integer.

My attempt:

\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{2n}-1}{x^2-1}&=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\left(x-e^\frac{ik\pi}{n}\right)\left(x-e^\frac{-ik\pi}{n}\right)\right) \\
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{2i}&=\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(x-e^\frac{ik\pi}{n}\right)\right)\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(x-e^\frac{-ik\pi}{n}\right)\right)
\end{align*}

How should I proceed further? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Multiply the two factors and get the expression containing cosine term.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1959351/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3957603/42969

Comment: Also there is a sign error. The factors are $(x-e^{\pm ik\pi/n}) $.